# Calling native libraries in Flutter using Platform Channels

Tags: java, android, interop, flutter

Using [platform channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/), Flutter can interop with the native platform (i.e. reading battery level). On Android, this would require calling a Java method.

I'd like to use a third-party Java SDK (for AWS Cognito). Can I put this library somewhere in my `/android`, and interact with it? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you haven't already got a plugin project started, create one.

Gather the third party jars somewhere - don't put them in the *pluginproject*/android/... folder.

Open the plugin project in your IDE - in my case IDEA - and add the third party jars to the Java classpath. (In IDEA, click Project Structure / Modules / select *pluginName*_android / Dependencies tab / green PlusSign / jars or directories - and select the individual jars or the whole folder. Leave the scope as compile and don't check export.)

Implement your android-specific code in Java (or Kotlin) in *pluginproject*/android/src/main/java/*com/yourcompany*.../.../*Pluginname*Plugin.java, where you will now be able to use the classes declared by the third party jars.

Add the dependencies to gradle so that it will compile. In *pluginproject*/android/build.gradle (NOTE - there are several build.gradles) add this at the end - after the android {} section

```
dependencies {
    implementation files('../../../java/someapi/somejar.jar')
}
```

The path must be relative to the *pluginproject*/android folder. You can specify a whole folder with this syntax instead

```
implementation fileTree(dir: '../../../somewhere/somefolder', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Run the example application provided in the plugin project.

I'm not sure why it's not possible to put the third party jars in, say, *pluginproject*/android/lib, but that causes a dex error for me, whereas, leaving them outside of the *pluginproject*/ folder works.

I've only ever used well-behaved third party jars (no JNI, don't create their own Threads, etc).

Comment: i didn't get implementation to work unless i added the dependencies to android/app/build.gradle instead of android/build.gradle

Comment: hi can you make a video for this plz? i want to use iText and it's not clear for me :(

Answer (score 12):

**Yes you can.**

> You can see the [documentation](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) on that or if you want you can see
>   [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nJrGKyRlPQ). It is helpful if you are using SDK that gives you
>   native code for both Android and iOS, otherwise it will be difficult.
>   Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The Android side of flutter uses Gradle (the same as any other android project). If you have an existing android app, you can probably port over most of the same settings from your gradle files.

Unless you've already done that and have a system for managing the jars, **I would not recommend** copying the jar files directly into your project & therefore source control.

Instead, use gradle's build-in dependency resolution. You should be able to follow [Amazon's android sdk set-up directions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html). The difference is that you'll have to hook up the calls to the SDK through method channels and write your own interop code.