# Creating flutter plugin that depends upon native library

Tags: android, package, native, flutter

I'm trying to create a plugin that relies upon AWS' Mobile SDK (In Java). It says to put

```
implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
```

inside the `app/build.grade`. However, when I'm developing that plugin as per the [documentation](https://flutter.io/developing-packages/#plugin), there is no `app/` folder within the plugin's android root (there is one in the example project, but I don't think that's where I'm supposed to put it).

Specifically, I'm creating the plugin using this command:

```
flutter create --template=plugin hello
```

Where should I put this? Should I download the .jar itself, and put it in the project.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

When using a `plugin`, add your gradle dependencies in `[projectFolder]/android/build.gradle`. At the bottom, below the android section, add a dependencies section like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
}
```

Then run the example application provided by the plugin project. Gradle will fetch the dependencies.

Comment: What if you have the file locally and it's not hosted anywhere? Like a local jar for example.

Comment: @MisterJimson see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels/50026052#50026052

Comment: Worked like a charm) My mistake was to add dependencies into [projectFolder]/android/app/build.gradle instead that resulted in my plugin not being able to see added dependencies. Moving it to [projectFolder]/android/build.gradle solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a plugin package for that

```
flutter create --template=plugin hello
```

`--template=package` is for packages that contain only Dart code.

Comment: I think that's actually what I ran, and I wrote the wrong thing in the question (sorry). Anyhow, I ran that command exactly and I have the same issue. There is no `/app` directory in the `/android`. Should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: Why are you looking for an `app/` directory anyway? https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/ contains lots of examples