# How use native libraries in flutter?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to be able to use a native library for example GLIDE in my flutter android project.

I have included gradle in the folder android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: '*.aar', dir: 'libs')
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    }
```

However when i run `./gradlew build` command it doesn't compile GLIDE, in addition when i go into the java folder android/src/main/java ManActivity.java

i try to type in Glide but it remains unresolved method.

please help.

Comment: Yes but the question is "How to use native libraries in flutter".

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this question: [Calling native libraries in Flutter using Platform Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels) you will have to create a new plugin project with the specific library you want. However as @dr3k said you can just use the flutter image widget.

Comment: i see, but my main goal is to learn how to add libraries using gradle in flutter. Also should i use the same method in your link if I want to add google's support libraries ?

Comment: Most google support libraries already have futter versions of them, so you can just add them to your project as you normaly would any flutter packages/plugins.