# How to use Flutter and access Native SDKs components with iOS/Swift and Android/Kotlin?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm testing out Flutter. I would like to integrate some iOS/Android specific SDKs. How do I add the SDKs to the correct OS folders and access the SDK? Is this possible with Flutter?

Comment: Flutter has system to allow you to call platform specific code - and also make calls the other way. See [platform channels](https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). To package that custom code into a reusable package use [plugins](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling native libraries in Flutter using Platform Channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels)