# 3rd party native library for Flutter package

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, cocoapods

If I need to create a [flutter package](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) for an existing library OR pod I am interested in some clarifications:

In the case of a new package for a **library (.framework)** ... will I add this in the `Pods/Development Pods/hello/Classes/` location? I suppose not in the Runner project since the code to implement the channels and extra native implementation is in that location, as mentioned in the flutter package documentation.

In the case of a new package for a **pod** ... I suppose I add the new pod in the podfile and then should I run pod update? or?

Some additional resources I have gone through and maybe missed something:

[Integrating third-party Native SDKs in Flutter](https://blog.solutelabs.com/integrating-third-party-native-sdks-in-flutter-df418829dcf7) + [the git repo](https://github.com/solutelabs/Flutchat?source=post_page-----df418829dcf7----------------------)

[This stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels) which is very android oriented.