# Flutter Smartphone App sync with watchOS and wearOS app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, wear-os, watchos

I want to build an Flutter app that is supposed to run on iPhones and Android Phones.
Also it has an smaller app "sibling" that is supposed to run on an Apple Watch and WearOS watch.

If I see it right, Flutter is not supporting by it self to write Smartwatch Apps.
My idea is to write the smartwatch apps in their native language and the phone app with Flutter.

What is the best way to implement an communication between smartwatch app (native) and phone app (Flutter)?
It would be awesome, if it is working even if an iPhone is combined with an Wear OS device and vice versa:

| Phone | Smartwatch |
| --- | --- |
| Android | Wear OS |
| Android | watchOS |
| iOS | Wear OS |
| iOS | watchOS |

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: For Android, It's probably calling through to the native Android APIs you can use on mobile to talk to the wear data layer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels and https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/data-layer