# DantSu / ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

I am using DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android library to print on my bluetooth printer. The library accepts data to print as a String. It uses `[L][C][R]` tags to left align, center align and right align the content respectively.

The content is coming from an API and I pass it straight to the print function. The problem I am facing right now is that I am trying to migrate the app to Flutter and I can't find a library that accepts the above mentioned `[L][C][R]` tags to print.

Is there any libraries available I can use to achieve this.

Link to the library : https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you looking for a flutter library with the same features of your current library?

Comment: Maybe you could use the native android library inside your flutter projekt? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020347/calling-native-libraries-in-flutter-using-platform-channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this problem. I replaced `[L][C][R]` tags with the actual byte codes used to align content in the printer. Codes I used are mentioned below

```
RIGHT = '\x1Ba2'
LEFT = '\x1Ba0'
CENTER = '\x1Ba1'
```

The flutter printer library used is https://pub.dev/packages/esc_pos_utils